# Complex looping or function in R

Tags: r

So I have recently started to code in general and I am stuck here for days.

In a simple scale, I have two dataframes and practically what I need to do is this

`(moduletotals$Freq[3] - totals_df$Freq[1])`

subtracting total of darkorange module, cluster 1 from frequency of "2'-deoxyribonucleotide biosynthesis" in darkorange module cluster 1 for every row of `totals_df`.

but I have so many data that I need to build a loop, function or something like that where the function can find frequency of total of the module and cluster in question from the individual sample. Something along these lines

```
> moduletotals$module == totals_df$module & 
    moduletotals$cluster == totals_df$cluster
```

print `freq` of the row that was found and subtract it from frequency of totals_df row in question

and I am completely lost here.

**moduletotals**

| module | cluster | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| darkgreen | 1 | 12 |
| darkgrey | 1 | 408 |
| darkorange | 1 | 355 |
| darkred | 1 | 11 |
| darkturquoise | 1 | 12 |
| grey | 1 | 22 |

**totals_df**

| Class_description | module | cluster | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2'-deoxyribonucleotide biosynthesis | darkorange | 1 | 1 |
| 2'-deoxyribonucleotide biosynthesis | darkgrey | 2 | 1 |
| 2'-deoxyribonucleotide biosynthesis | darkorange | 2 | 3 |
| Adaptions and atypical conditions | darkorange | 1 | 1 |
| Adaptions and atypical conditions | darkgrey | 2 | 1 |
| Aerobic | darkgrey | 1 | 4 |
| Aerobic | darkorange | 1 | 3 |
| Aerobic | grey60 | 1 | 2 |
| Aerobic | lightyellow | 1 | 3 |
| Aerobic | royalblue | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `left_join` between dataframes:

```r
library(tidyverse)

module <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  module = c(
    "darkgreen",
    "darkgrey",
    "darkorange",
    "darkred",
    "darkturquoise",
    "grey"
  ),
  cluster = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  freq = c(12L, 408L, 355L, 11L, 12L, 22L)
)

totals <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  class_description = c(
    "Adaptions and atypical conditions",
    "Adaptions and atypical conditions",
    "Aerobic",
    "Aerobic",
    "Aerobic",
    "Aerobic",
    "Aerobic"
  ),
  module = c(
    "darkorange",
    "darkgrey",
    "darkgrey",
    "darkorange",
    "grey60",
    "lightyellow",
    "royalblue"
  ),
  cluster = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  freq = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L)
)

totals %>%
  left_join(module,
            by = c("module", "cluster")) %>%
  replace_na(list(freq.y = 0))
#>                   class_description      module cluster freq.x freq.y
#> 1 Adaptions and atypical conditions  darkorange       1      1    355
#> 2 Adaptions and atypical conditions    darkgrey       2      1      0
#> 3                           Aerobic    darkgrey       1      4    408
#> 4                           Aerobic  darkorange       1      3    355
#> 5                           Aerobic      grey60       1      2      0
#> 6                           Aerobic lightyellow       1      3      0
#> 7                           Aerobic   royalblue       1      1      0


module %>%
  left_join(
    totals %>%
      group_by(module, cluster) %>%
      summarise(freq = sum(freq),
                .groups = "drop"),
    by = c("module", "cluster")
  ) %>%
  replace_na(list(freq.y = 0))
#>          module cluster freq.x freq.y
#> 1     darkgreen       1     12      0
#> 2      darkgrey       1    408      4
#> 3    darkorange       1    355      4
#> 4       darkred       1     11      0
#> 5 darkturquoise       1     12      0
#> 6          grey       1     22      0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot sometimes you only need another perspective